# Pandas subset rows according to string-match

Tags: python, pandas

I have used the `string_grouper` package in Python to generate a list of the common names between two databases of company info. The resulting data-frame `matches` shows the company names from DB1 (`left_side`) and DB2 (`right_side`) above a certain string-similarity threshold:

[image]

Now, I want to reduce DB1 to just include the rows where the company name is present in `matches['left_side']`. (Because info in DB1 is useless if not complemented by info on that company from DB2. So I want only the companies in both)

How do I do this? The names are present in DB1 in a column 'names' but e.g.

```
rslt_df = DB1[DB1['names'] in matches['left_side']]
```

gave me an error (`'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`).

DB1 is pretty large (`matches` ends up with about 10,000-20,000 rows, DB1 has 2000000+ rows) so please bear this in mind speed-wise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happens because `DB1['names']` is series while `in` operator expects single element on the left.

Try using [pandas.Series.isin() function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
rslt_df = DB1[DB1['names'].isin(matches['left_side'])]
```